# Angular - Load component using ngOnInit

Tags: angular, ionic4

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get one of my components to load when the page loads.

Here is what I got:

activity.page.ts:

```
export class ActivityPage implements OnInit {

  page = "friends"; // page is the ngModel name

  friends: Friends[];
  selectedFriends: Friends;  

  nearme: Nearme[];
  selectedNearme: Nearme;

  constructor(private friendService: FriendsService, private nearmeService: 
   NearmeService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.friends = this.friendService.getFriends();
    this.nearme = this.nearmeService.getNearme();
    console.log(this.friends);
  }

  selectFriends(friends: Friends): void {
    this.selectedFriends = friends;
    this.selectedNearme = null;
    console.log(friends);
  }

  selectNearme(nearme: Nearme): void {
    this.selectedNearme = nearme;
    this.selectedFriends = null;
  }

  segmentChanged(ev: any) {
    console.log('Segment changed', ev);
  }

}
```

activity.page.html:

```
<ion-segment-button class="tab-label" value="friends" (click)="selectFriends(friends)" margin-start>
    Friends
</ion-segment-button>
<ion-segment-button class="tab-label" value="near_me" (click)="selectNearme(nearme)">
    Near Me
</ion-segment-button>
<app-friends *ngIf="selectedFriends" [friends]="selectedFriends"></app-friends>
<app-nearme *ngIf="selectedNearme" [nearme]="selectedNearme"></app-nearme>
```

friends.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class FriendsService {
  private friends: Friends[] = [];

  constructor(
    private backend: BackendService,
    private logger: Logger
  ) { }

  getFriends() {
    this.backend.getAll(Friends).then( (friends: Friends[]) => {
      this.logger.log(`Fetched ${friends.length} friends.`);
      this.friends.push(...friends); // fill cache
    });
    return this.friends;
  }
}
```

backend.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class BackendService {
  constructor(private logger: Logger) {}

  getAll(type: Type<any>): PromiseLike<any[]> {
    if (type === Friends) {
      // TODO: get from the database
      return Promise.resolve<Friends[]>(FRIENDS);
    }
    if (type === Nearme) {
      // TODO: get from the database
      return Promise.resolve<Nearme[]>(NEARME);
    }
    let err = new Error('Cannot get object of this type');
    this.logger.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
}
```

When the page loads the content is empty. I need to click on the segment button to the load the component HTML. I want the `app-friends` component to show on page load.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have tried the answers below and they do not work 100%.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Can you paste FriendService.getFriends() there? If it is ajax method, you can confirm it sent after ngInit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong on your `ngOnInit` - you are just hiding your components based on conditions - try to assign value to your `selectedFriends` or `selectedNearMe` since both are `null` or `undefined` when the page loads

So when you trigger click either one of it gets value and you are able to see your components

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.friends = this.friendService.getFriends();
    this.nearme = this.nearmeService.getNearme();
    this.selectedFriends = this.friends;
  }
```

The above code will display your `app-friends` - if nothing works try to show/hide using `[hidden]` property on your components

Hopes this helps - Happy coding :)

Comment: This works, but it gives an error for `this.selectedFriends` that says: `[ts]
Type 'Friends[]' is not assignable to type 'Friends'.
  Property 'avatar' is missing in type 'Friends[]'.`

Comment: Yep the type of your `selectedFriends` seems to be of `Friends` try to assign only one object from `friends` array like this `this.selectedFriends = this.friends[0]` - now this will come to a cass that either your friends got binded correctly or not - since you are reading it from your service try to subscribe it and read your results

Comment: Best way is to use `boolean` on your conditions instead of `objects` - set `selectedFriends` as bool - flase on initial page load and after binding your object set it as true that will do the magic mostly - make sure when you click to show or hide again - toggle with your another component

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am still very new to this and learning as I go. Thanks for any help you give.

Comment: Share a stackblitz i will help you :-)

Comment: `this.selectedFriends = friends; this.selectedNearme = null;` just add this line in your `ngOnInit()` or call the function `selectFriends` on your init i think this will slove your problem

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not in the ngOnInit, is on the conditions of the ngIf.

You are showing app-friend when selectedFriends is not null and app-nearme when selectedNearme is not null, which are setted when the button are clicked.

In my opinion the best option is to change the ngIf conditions to page === "friends" and page === "near_me" like this:

```
<app-friends *ngIf="page === 'friends'" [friends]="selectedFriends"></app-friends>
<app-nearme *ngIf="page === 'near_me'" [nearme]="selectedNearme"></app-nearme>
```

Other option is to use a swhich like the docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#segment

Also I am not sure if is correct your code on the functions binded to the (click) events of the buttons but perhaps some code is missing here because is not part of the problem :)

Make sure that you have a selectedFriends if is needed in app-friend, because with the change I suggested app-friend will be loaded at the start ;)

**Edit:** Adding switch example:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="page">
  <ion-segment-button class="tab-label" value="friends" (click)="selectFriends(friends)" margin-start>
    Friends
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button class="tab-label" value="near_me" (click)="selectNearme(nearme)">
    Near Me
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<div [ngSwitch]="page">
    <app-friends *ngSwitchCase="'friends'" [friends]="selectedFriends"></app-friends>
    <app-nearme *ngSwitchCase="'near_me'" [nearme]="selectedNearme"></app-nearme>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried changing the ngIf conditions, but that did not work. I'm not sure I understand your comment about (click) events.

Comment: does it give you an error or doesn't do anything? if the condition is ok the page variable is set as friends at the start and will change when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: sorry, the comment was incomplete! My question was that I don't understand on **(click)="selectFriends(friends)** how does it works, because you pass as param all the friends array and the method on the ts expect only one Friends not all the array, the same happens with **(click)="selectNearme(nearme)"**

Comment: That is a really good question and I wish I had the answer lol. I am still learning so i'm not fully sure how it works just yet. I got the example from here: https://stackblitz.com/angular/gxgllrlnaje?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-list.component.html

Comment: this example works because it iterates over heroes and each item has only one hero, I am not sure what is javascript doing when the function is called haha, do you have the code of your child components? in order to know what do they need in the inputs. Also take a look at the edition of my answer ;)

Comment: @iamthestreets did you try the switch option instead of ngif that I added at the end of my answer?

Comment: I updated my question with more code. I tried the switch option and that did not work.